# Inter-module communication binder-agnostic

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Been lurking around the Spring docs regarding this and the only thing I could find regarding inter-module communication is the following...

> While Spring Cloud Stream makes it easy for individual modules to connect to messaging systems, the typical scenario for Spring Cloud Stream is the creation of multi-module pipelines, where modules are sending data to each other. This can be achieved by correlating the input and output destinations of adjacent modules, as in the following example.
>
> Supposing that the design calls for the `time-source` module to send
>   data to the `log-sink` module, we will use a common destination named
>   foo for both modules. `time-source` will set
>   `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output=foo` and `log-sink` will set
>   `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input=foo`.

Tried a brief test creating a module inside a test project, which is basically a `Sink` which receives the data from the parent `Processor` that gathers data from a Kinesis input stream and spits it into an output.

```
# Processor config    
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination= to-stage
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination= sample-input-stream
```

---

```
# Sink config
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination= to-stage
```

While doing this, the following message prior running the module is prompt.

```
o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KinesisStreamProvisioner   : Using Kinesis stream for outbound: to-stage
o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KinesisStreamProvisioner   : Stream 'to-stage' not found. Create one...
```

Is there any config or workaround so that inter-module communication takes place using other mechanisms (e.g. within the container) or once the binder (Kinesis, Rabbit, ...) is configured, all those communications are performed using those cloud streams? Which means having `n` more streams as modules are, which increases costs and maintenance.

If I want to keep everything **with just an input and output stream**, should I just use the `Processor` implementation within only one Spring Boot app and do the data treatment within?

I would like to avoid this (if possible) in order to have a cleaner architecture and not compact everything within one single Spring application.

Comment: Are you asking about communicating between n+ modules within the single JVM instance bypassing the binder?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky exactly, don't really know if there's an option using a custom-made binder which works with sockets, or anything like that... Just thinking out loud, don't really know if that would be even feasible to do.

Comment: Well, as a module it is by design that the application/microservice is isolated and in itself constitutes an instance of the JVM. There is however a way to address the same architecture (pipes-and-filters) using [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) framework. In fact Spring Cloud Stream is build on top of Spring Integration where additional layer of binders is added.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky oh nice, didn't know about it! Has something to do with the Gateway notation? Sorry if this sounds really straightforward but this is my first serious approach with Spring and feels quite overwhelming at first.

Comment: Understood. [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) is where you can get started pretty quickly. Go wit the 'basic' firs to get a general idea and then you can switch to 'dsl' where you can create real pipelines.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky awesome, thanks a lot! If you want to answer the question with some of that so I can approve and give points would be great :)

Comment: That's ok, I am not here for points (that's for others). . . you happy I am happy !cheers!